# Saving an array object as a string within a picker view?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

So I am working with a `pickerview` and need a string to equal one of several things that I have stored in an `array`. The `pickerview` code for the components looks like this.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (row) {
    case 0:
        image.image = image1;
        email = EmailArray[1];
        break;
    case 1:
        image.image = image2;
        email = EmailArray[3];
        break;
    case 2:
        image.image = image3;
        email = EmailArray[5];
        break;
    }

NSLog(@"%@", email)

}
```

This code works just fine as far as I can tell. The `NSLog` here returns the correct email every time. The user then presses a button that utilizes the "email" string. Here is the first part of that code.

```
- (IBAction)sendFeedback:(id)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"%@", email);
}
```

Only here the `NSLog` does not return the correct email. It just freezes the program and gives me a threading error that points at that `NSLog`. Am I not passing the array object to the string correctly?

If I change the code to this it works just fine.

```
switch (row) {
case 0:
    image.image = image1;
    email = @"testEmail@gmail.com";
    break;
```

After this both `NSLogs` will display the test email.

Please help me figure out this problem. If you need more information just ask.

EDIT

Here is the beginning of my ViewController.h file.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
<UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> {
    NSMutableArray *EmailArray;
}
```

Here is where email is declared in the ViewController.h.

```
@implementation ViewController
NSString *email;
```

The error I get looks like this.

```
Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x14)
```

Comment: Log your array and post what you get (`NSLog(@"%@", [EmailArray description]);` - perhaps your array does not contain what you think it contains.

Comment: I had tried that. It contains exactly what I want it to.

Comment: ...if your array definitely contains only `NSString`s, what's the *scope* of your `EmailArray` variable (i.e, how are you declaring it)?

Comment: I declared it in the ViewController.h file as an NSMutableArray.

Comment: Can you share that code? It doesn't look like a property.

Comment: I edited my original post to include that.

Comment: That array's called `loadedNameArray`...which is different from `EmailArray`. Where's `EmailArray` coming from?

Comment: Sorry I copied the wrong line of code... The names do match up.

Comment: Where (and how) is `email` declared? Can you post the error you get? An [**exception breakpoint**](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions) would also help

Answer (score 0):

You should not declared `email` as an instance var. An `NSString` must be declared as a property with copy modifier

```
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString* email;
```

Comment: why `copy` and not `strong`?

Comment: @stevekohls Alwways use copycopy for `NSString` (`NSString` is actually a cluster of classes - that means your `NSString` instance may belong to a subclass, not `NSString` itself)

Comment: I tried this and it still gave me the same error at the same place. Should I declare my array in this way too?

Comment: @Logiwan992 if you initialize the array only once for the whole life time of the view controller, you can keep it an instance var (it will be deallocated when the view is deallocated). If you reassign it some where during its lifetime, it should be declared as `@property (strong)`, may I see the code that initializes / changes `EmailArray`?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is not retained in memory, hence the crash.

You have two options

1. Add `[email retain]` after you assign it
2. Enable ARC and it will retain that variable for you.